# Calendar#get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) vs TimeUnits.MILLISECONDS.toHours()

Tags: java, android, calendar

Do you guys know why this happens, why `Calendar` returns `1` for `hours` while it is definitely not `1`, but `0.008` in this concrete case:

```
millisUntilFinished = 30 * 1000

public void test(long millisUntilFinished) {
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(millisUntilFinished);
Timber.i("Hours: " + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
Timber.i("Hours using TimeUnit: " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished));
}
```

Output:

```
Hours: 01
Hours using TimeUnit: 00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timezones. If your `Calendar` is in `UTC+1`, that's the result you'll get.